# How to pass AntiForgery Token to controller without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have this jquery function and I want to pass an antiforgery token to the controller to be validated. However, my current method is returning an error 400 no matter if I pass it through the header or through the body.

I put this empty form at the top of my page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

This is the jquery function. I have the requestverificationtoken in the header and the body but it doesn't work.

```
$("#eventGenerateButton").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var event_form_data = {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": token,
        "StartDate": $("#eventStartDate").val(),
        "EndDate": $("#eventEndDate").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GenerateEventLogsReport", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token},
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(event_form_data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            GenerateReport(result,"EventLogs");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public FileResult GenerateEventLogsReport([FromBody]GenericReportDateViewModel Input)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class,
            AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
///this attribute is for validating antiforgery, no matter how it's sent.
///It doesn't care if the token is in the header or body, and the body can be stringified.
public sealed class MyValidateAntiForgeryAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }
        
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        
            /* Note:  Antiforgery tokens are passed twice from a page.  Once from
             * the post itself, and once as a cookie to verify against it.  The
             * values do not match.  They are two halves of a whole and both get
             * passed into the validation routine. */
            var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
            //try header first
            var token = httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
            //try normal method
            if (token == null)
            {
                for (int cl = 0; cl < httpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Count; cl++)
                {
                    if (httpContext.Request.Form.Keys[cl] == "__RequestVerificationToken")
                    {
                        token = httpContext.Request.Form[httpContext.Request.Form.Keys[cl]];
                    }
                }
            }
            //try url
            if (token == null)
            {
                for (int cl = 0; cl < httpContext.Request.QueryString.Keys.Count; cl++)
                {
                    if (httpContext.Request.QueryString.Keys[cl] == "__RequestVerificationToken")
                    {
                        token = httpContext.Request.QueryString[httpContext.Request.QueryString.Keys[cl]];
                    }
                }
            }
            /* if still null, check to see if it's in a json string.
               this section will retrieve the token out of a serialized dataset.
            */
            if (token == null)
            {
                string json;
                var position = httpContext.Request.InputStream.Position;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 8192, true))
                {
                    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    //you MUST reset the input stream to start or you will break post.
                    httpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    try
                    {
                        var jsonObj = Json.Decode(json); //attempt to parse into json object.  
                        token = jsonObj["__RequestVerificationToken"];
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //eat the parse errors.  That simply means it's not json.
                    }
                }
            }
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookie?.Value, token);
        
    }
}
```

You can't validate an antiforgery token with the stock validator in these situations:

1. the json is serialized.
2. you pass it in the header.
3. you pass it in the url.

If you need to do any of these things, you need to write your own antiforgery check so you can find the token in the passed data.
I have written an antiforgery check that does the following:

1. Checks for the token in the url
2. Checks for it in the serialized data
3. checks for it in the header.
   Feel free to use it.  Note that this (on purpose) is not filtering out gets.  You may want to add that if you add it at class level.

Answer (score 0):

Remove token from `event_form_data` , then try to send in request header like

```
var event_form_data = {
    "StartDate": $("#eventStartDate").val(),
    "EndDate": $("#eventEndDate").val(),
    };
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/AjaxPost",
    method: "POST",      
    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": token},
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(event_form_data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you get the `token`?And make sure the data is correct.

Comment: var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(); This is how I get it.

Comment: Sorry for late.It works well in my local..Could you share a reproducible demo?

Comment: does this even work?  The antiforgery check in the controller ignores headers by default, and is looking for a key starting with __ anyway

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your controller signature to this:

```
public FileResult GenerateEventLogsReport(string __RequestVerificationToken, string StartDate, string EndDate)
{

}
```

Comment: Huh? It won't even hit the controller signature due to it failing the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] section